# Booting only into GRUB prompt, no GRUB GUI - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2

Is there a way to get GRUB GUI back from GUI CLI so I can get a shell?  I need to edit a file to fix the issue but I can't even get the GRUB GUI (tried left /right shift)

This is on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Grub does not have a gui, it does have a menu when working. If you are getting grub> or grub rescue> then grub needs repairs. Often easier using your Ubuntu live installer and Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: That's too bad that as that'd be preferable to just fix the GRUB menu as that'd give me a proper shell, I did try Ubuntu live installer but it wasn't able to detect the SSD.

Comment: If UEFI you get into grub menu with Escape, perhaps several times. But grub's command line is very limited.